# Chinese characters in form submission

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, post, cjk

Client page:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Catchup Scheduler" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
<form action="next.php" method="POST" >
<input type="text" name="programme_name"></br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
```

Server page:

```
$name = $_POST['programme_name'];

mysql_query("SET character_set_client=utf8",$con);
mysql_query("SET character_set_connection=utf8", $con);
mysql_query("SET character_set_results=utf8", $con);

$query = "Select * from programme where Programme_name Like '%".$name."'";
```

Problem is although there is Chinese text in the database, the query always returns `ZERO(none)`.
If I print the POST value `$name` it displays the correct text with the Chinese characters.

but if i store it in a variable, such as:

```
$name= "valuevalue ( 官话 )";
$query = "Select * from programme where Programme_name Like '%".$name."'";
```

It produces results.
How could this be, in POST it doesn't but static value declaration it does?
My OS is XP SP3.

Is there a problem in the "internal" representation of Chinese characters if it is in POST?
Do I need to set something in my OS to support Chinese representation?

Comment: I also tried this in JSP and same... I wonder if this has to do with something else

Answer (score 0):

You are feeding mySQL unescaped, raw input.

Use `mysql_real_escape_string` on your input string or better yet use PDO to talk to the database.